# Stored Query on nested elements from an INSPIRE WFS 2.0 download service

Tags: arcgis-server, wfs, error, getfeature

Is there a way to create a stored query from this WFS 2.0.0 service that filters exactly an nested element?

http://geoportal.ancpi.ro/arcgis/rest/services/AU/AU_Download/GeoDataServer/exts/InspireFeatureDownload/service?VERSION=2.0.0&SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&STOREDQUERY_ID=GETauByNationalCode&code=11940

This is an extract of the GML:

```
<au:AdministrativeUnit gml:id="auAdmUnitS.1387">
   <au:nationalCode>11940</au:nationalCode>
   <au:inspireId>
     <base:Identifier>
      <base:localId>1.29.11940</base:localId>
      <base:namespace>RO.Ancpi.AU</base:namespace>
      <base:versionId xsi:nil="true"/>
     </base:Identifier>
    </au:inspireId>
</au:AdministrativeUnit>
```

I would ideally like to be able to filter the data based on these two properties

- au:InspireId/base:Identifier/base:namespace
- au:InspireId/base:Identifier/base:localId

To do this I created a stored query with the following definition:

```
<DescribeStoredQueriesResponse xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0 http://geoportal.ancpi.ro/arcgis/rest/directories/arcgisforinspire/schema/ogc/wfs/2.0/wfs.xsd">
    <wfs:StoredQueryDescription id="GetSQ2">
        <Title>GetSQ2</Title>
        <wfs:QueryExpressionText language="urn:ogc:def:queryLanguage:OGC-WFS::WFS_QueryExpression" returnFeatureTypes="gml:AbstractFeature">
            <wfs:Query typeNames="au:AdministrativeUnit">
                <fes:Filter>
                    <fes:And>
                        <fes:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                            <fes:ValueReference>au:inspireId/base:Identifier/base:localId</fes:ValueReference>
                            <fes:Literal>1.29.11940</fes:Literal>
                        </fes:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                        <fes:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                            <fes:ValueReference>au:inspireId/base:Identifier/base:namespace</fes:ValueReference>
                            <fes:Literal>RO.Ancpi.AU</fes:Literal>
                        </fes:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                    </fes:And>
                </fes:Filter>
            </wfs:Query>
        </wfs:QueryExpressionText>
    </wfs:StoredQueryDescription>
</DescribeStoredQueriesResponse>
```

When I create a GetFeature Request using this Stored Query:
http://geoportal.ancpi.ro/arcgis/rest/services/AU/AU_Download/GeoDataServer/exts/InspireFeatureDownload/service?VERSION=2.0.0&SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&STOREDQUERY_ID=GetSQ2

I get this error message:
`Operation request contains an invalid parameter value. The PropertyName "au:inspireId/base:Identifier/base:localId" is in step "basex:Identifier" not compliant with the Application schema.`